# jQuery 1.9 toggle function for animate script

Tags: jquery

I have used this script for a long time, and I'm barely good at jQuery, so when I saw that this was removed from v.1.9x of jQuery, I couldn't locate a fix that made any sense to me (except that adding the migrate plugin fixes it but adds a lot of script). Any help would be appreciated so I can learn how to replicate this behavior. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#switcher-wrapper .toggle").toggle(function () {
    $("#switcher-wrapper").animate({
        left: "-1px"
    });
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    return false;
}, function () {
    $("#switcher-wrapper").animate({
        left: "-242px"
    });
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
    return false;
});
```

});

This works in 1.8.3 but does odd stuff in 1.9 jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why event-based `.toggle()` isn't needed, and actually leads to duplicated code because the two toggled functions are separated.

- There is already a "selected" attribute on the element so there is no need for the internal state management of the event-based `.toggle()` method. The old code had the risk of the two state indications getting out of sync which is a common thing.
- The event is on the .toggle element below the wrapper so it would make sense to install the delegated event on the wrapper (unless you're removing the wrapper and rewriting it at some point).
- It might make the code more reusable to use `e.delegateTarget` instead of re-specifying the wrapper element. The delegate target is the element that is currently handling the delegated click event, as opposed to the innermost target that was clicked.
- Cicking rapidly on the .toggle element may cause it to bounce back and forth a while. The `.stop()` can help prevent that.

```

```
$("#switcher-wrapper").on("click", ".toggle", function (e) {
   var selected = $(this).hasClass("selected");
   $(e.delegateTarget).stop().animate({
      left: selected? "-242px" : "-1px"
   });
   $(this).toggleClass("selected", !selected);
});
```

```

http://jsfiddle.net/KmYES/

Answer (score 4):

Toggle has been removed from 1.9 ([see here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed))

Do like this instead :

```
$("body").on('click', '#switcher-wrapper .toggle' function () {

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {

        $("#switcher-wrapper").animate({
            left: "-242px"
        });
        $(this).removeClass("selected");

    } else {

       $("#switcher-wrapper").animate({
            left: "-1px"
        });
        $(this).addClass("selected");

    }
    return false;

});
```